# Where can I download the TarWriter rubygem?

Tags: ruby, installation, tar

I can't find this anywhere... the rubydoc is all over a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?gcx=w&ix=c1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=gem%20package%20tarwriter&qscrl=1#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&safe=off&qscrl=1&source=hp&q=ruby%20tarwriter&pbx=1&oq=ruby%20tarwriter&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=4398l4678l1l4878l5l3l0l0l0l1l359l359l3-1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b571422ac7922aeb&biw=1238&bih=917) for this package, but where is the the gem/install command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's part of rubygems; why do you want to download it? Look in `rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb`.

```
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :001 > require 'rubygems/package'
 => true 
ruby-1.9.2-p0 :002 > Gem::Package::TarWriter
 => Gem::Package::TarWriter
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm a little confused. Where is this file on my harddisk? Is it in my ruby installation?

Comment: @TonyR I have no idea; probably. I use `rvm`, so I looked in my `rubies` directory, but it should be in wherever your rubygems lib is located.

Comment: Yes, it is. In my case the path is: /home/pva/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-head/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb. In the worst case try "find / -name 'tar_writer.rb'" command.

Comment: Ah, okay it was in my Ruby installation after all - C:\Ruby192\lib\ruby\1.9.1
Thanks everyone!

Comment: @TonyR Cool :) `find` and `grep` (and `xargs`) are your friend ;)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are referring to the `TarWriter` class available as part of the RubyGems sources, https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/blob/master/lib/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb.

Answer (score 0):

found [that](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/RubyGems/RubyGems-19/RubyGems/lib/rubygems/package/tar_writer.rb) while googling for "tarwriter filetype:rb"

if you go [here](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/RubyGems/RubyGems-19/RubyGems/lib/rubygems/package/), there are some related files.